# What happens when I don't give input to some command that expects it?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, shell

Some commands expect input, like `cat`, `sed`, `head`, `tail`, etc. When I run such a command without giving it any input, it waits for me to enter something. I tried to enter different things afterward but it only returned what I typed in.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. They will read the input, do whatever they're supposed to do with it and stop at EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-D sends an "End of File" (EOF) character, telling the tool that you're done giving input. The tool will exit itself and return you to the shell

Ctrl-C kills the tool and returns you to the shell

Ctrl-Z pauses the tool and keeps it loaded while returning you to the shell. You can then choose to resume the tool in the foreground or background with the "fg" and "bg" commands.